# How can I safely and permanently kill SearchApp.exe and delete its cache files in Windows 10 22H2?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v22h2

I've been trying to follow instructions from

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/734430/how-can-i-permanently-disable-or-just-delete-searchappexe/

because I'm uncomfortable with the personal information saved in `~/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy/LocalState/DeviceSearchCache/AppCacheBUNCH-OF-NUMBERS-REPRESENTING-A-64-BIT-WINDOWS-FILETIME.txt`. For instance, it's got information about some of my Firefox tabs:

`"System.FileName":{"Value":"firefox","Type":12},"System.ConnectedSearch.JumpList":{"Value":"[{\"Name\":\"Frequent\",\"Type\":4,\"Items\":[{\"Type\":2,\"Name\":\"How to Import Intermediate and Root Certificates Using MMC\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Mozilla Firefox\\\\firefox.exe\",\"Description\":\"How to Import Intermediate and Root Certificates Using MMC\"},{\"Type\":2,\"Name\":\"Internet Archive: Digital Library of Free & Borrowable Books, Movies, Music & Wayback Machine\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Mozilla Firefox\\\\firefox.exe\",\"Description\":\"Internet Archive: Digital Library of Free & Borrowable Books, Movies, Music & Wayback Machine\"},{\"Type\":2,\"Name\":\"Ars Technica\",\"Path\":\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Mozilla Firefox\\\\firefox.exe\",\"Description\":\"Ars Technica\"},`

Running Command Prompt with administrator privilege:

```
> taskkill /f /im SearchApp.exe
SUCCESS: The process "SearchApp.exe" with PID 9396 has been terminated.

> move .\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy .\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy.old
Access is denied.
        0 dir(s) moved.
```

After retrying that `move` command several times, I investigated. It seems `SearchApp.exe` is respawned with a new PID every time I kill it with `taskkill`. And using Resource Monitor (`resmon.exe`), plus Task Manager to look up the PIDs associated with `svchost.exe`, I discover that Cryptographic Services is using a subfolder of `Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy`, and that several dllhost.exe processes are using another subfolder of it.

This may have something to do with the fact that I'm using Windows 10 22H2, while the bleepingcomputer.com instructions were only up-to-date for Windows 10 2004.

Is there a way to permanently and safely kill SearchApp.exe and delete its cache files, or at least their containing folder, in Windows 10 22H2 and later?

**EDIT:** As requested in comments, here is a screenshot of SearchApp.exe's digital signature tab in Properties:

[image]

And its "general" tab:

[image]

**EDIT 2:** This screenshot of Resource Monitor shows that SearchApp.exe has a handle to the AppData folder, although it isn't to `LocalState/DeviceSearchCache`. Probably because this isn't the time of day at which it updates the cache:

[image]

**EDIT 3:** This screenshot of Task Manager shows SearchApp with (apparently) a status of "Suspended":

[image]

**EDIT 4:** The numbers in the filename use the Windows filetime format. As described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps#faq-about-programming-with-qpc-and-tsc :

> A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

A [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux/6161842#6161842) helpfully provides instructions on how to convert these to a Unix time. I was able to take the sequence of numbers in the most recent version of the AppCache file (133398601010854315), and convert it to a Unix time of 1695386501 (Fri Sep 22 2023 13:41:41 GMT+0100) - which was only one second different to the file's modification time in Windows Explorer.

This second was probably due to the division operation losing some precision, or maybe a leap second.

**EDIT 5:** After rebooting to install updates, this folder now contains *two* copies of the AppCache file, identical except for the different timestamps in their filenames. They've both updated to contain information about Firefox tabs I'd opened yesterday.

```
~/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy/LocalState/DeviceSearchCache
$ md5sum *.txt
8719a292214fc12f15b7c6c5bf9056a5 *AppCache133401956586656870.txt
8719a292214fc12f15b7c6c5bf9056a5 *AppCache133401956702714154.txt
18c12475040fdc68ce53f16f902ac061 *SettingsCache.txt
```

Comment: So you want to permanently remove the ability to search for files in your Windows installation? You can't just simply delete folders in WindowsApps even if you break all UWP applications, by taking ownership of the folder, that simply isn't the correct procedure.

Comment: @Ramhound I'd be satisfied with being able to delete that cache file, but I need to make sure `SearchApp.exe` stays dead while I do so, and the fact that it keeps respawning after the `taskkill` means I'm looking for a way to kill it permanently (or until I manually restart it). I almost never use Windows Search so probably wouldn't suffer from removing this ability. In the worst-case scenario, I guess I could re-enable it if needed.

Comment: There are more official methods for [disabling Windows Search](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-search-indexer-guide/).

Comment: Remove all folders from File Indexing, as @harrymc links, regenerate (empty) index, and all data should have been deleted.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The index (which I already regenerated) is a `.edb` file in a different folder, not this `.txt` file in a subfolder of my home directory. I'm pretty sure I removed all folders from indexing, but in any case what concerns me is that this file appears to cache information on a small subset of the Firefox tabs I have open and there's no way to clear it.

Comment: @harrymc Whatever sort of search this is, it's not the same thing as the main Windows Search. I stopped and disabled Windows Search in `services.msc` some time ago, but `SearchApp.exe` was not stopped by it. And the cache file I was talking about was regenerated earlier this morning - likely at exactly the point I brought my PC out of sleep.

Comment: Thanks to @Ramhound for the new tag, btw.

Comment: On deeper examination: My `SearchApp.exe` lives in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Search`, not in your folder. Whatever this is, is unknown. Please right-click it in Task Manager, select Properties and take screenshots of the General tab and the Digital Signatures tab, and add them to your post. I would suggest in the meantime to run deep antivirus scans of the computer.

Comment: @harrymc `SearchApp.exe` does not exist in this subfolder of `AppData`. It's this cache file which does. `SearchApp.exe`, for me at least, exists in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy`.

Comment: So this IS after all Windows Search, then why are you trying to modify `AppData`? I don't understand.

Comment: @harrymc The executable exists in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy`. The cache file exists in a subfolder of `C:\Users\McJa254\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy`. Note that both of these paths include a folder called `Microsoft.Windows.Search_cw5n1h2txyewy`. And in the screenshot of Resource Monitor I'm about to attach, SearchApp.exe can be seen to have a handle to at least one subfolder of that AppData folder.

Comment: It's not supposed to be running at all if Windows Search is turned off. The status of my `SearchApp.exe` is "Suspended". Whatever information you have in the folder `DeviceSearchCache` you may remove (put it away then delete after a few days). I would leave `SettingsCache.txt` in place.

Comment: It shows as "Suspended" in Task Manager for me as well - in fact, I think it's been "Suspended" all the way through. I'll attach another screenshot.

Comment: Additionally, whatever the bunch of numbers in the filename is, it looks like it's not a Unix timestamp with extra digits like I thought. I just took the current Unix time (1695375500) which doesn't match the numbers in the filename (AppCache133398457588135312.txt)

Comment: OK, I took the advice in the previous comment and removed the AppCache file. (Actually, I left the file in place but deleted its contents.) It's just been regenerated with a new bunch of numbers (133398601010854315), including having restored the offending information about my Firefox tabs. (The regeneration must have been a few minutes or even seconds ago.)

Comment: I've found some more information at https://github.com/dfirdetective/WinSearchAppCache

Comment: I now know what the numbers represented. They're a timestamp in the format described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps#faq-about-programming-with-qpc-and-tsc . By following the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161776/convert-windows-filetime-to-second-in-unix-linux/6161842#6161842 I was able to convert the numbers to a Unix timestamp, and to confirm that it matched the file's modification date.